# Button onclick refreshing page

Tags: jquery, html, button

I have a styled div that looks like a button:

```
    <form class="ui form segment" name="form" id="myForm" method="POST" style="max-width:950px;">

        <!-- Some fields omitted -->

        <!-- Normal button that has onclick event attached --> 
        <div class="ui blue submit button" id="applyButton" style="width:150px" name="apply">Update</div>


  <!-- 2 submit buttons -->

  <input type ="submit" class="ui blue submit button" id="publish" value = "Publish" style="width:150px" name="publish" onclick="submitForm('/write/submitWork'); this.disabled=true; this.className += ' disabled'; this.value='Sending…'; "/>

  <input class="ui orange submit button" id="saveasdraft" value ="Save as draft" style="width:160px" name="saveasdraft" onclick="submitForm('/write/submitWork'); this.disabled=true; this.className += ' disabled'; this.value='Sending…'; "/>

    </form>
```

Here is the `submitForm()` function that submits the form depending on which action was passed in:

```
function submitForm(action)
    {
        document.getElementById('myForm').action = action;
        document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
    }
```

I have attached an onclick event to it that gets some data from an ajax request and prints it on screen:

```
$(document).on('click', '#applyButton', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    // for each input radio button
    $('input[type=radio]').each(function () {
        // if the radio button is checked
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            if (!$("#characterList div:contains(" + $(this).val() + ")").length) {
                $('#characterList').append('<div class="ui card"><div class="content"> <div class="header">' + $(this).val() + '</div><div class="description"><p>' + getCharacterData($(this).val()) + '</p></div></div></div>');
            }
        } else {
            $("#characterList div:contains(" + $(this).val() + ")").remove();

        }

    });
});
```

The problem is that it refreshes the page and sometimes acts like a submit button for the form. I don't want it to do this.

Here is a [link](http://shabazejaz.co.uk/write/) to a live example. (Click on the blue 'Update' button in the characters section)

**EDIT:**

The link required the user to be logged in so you can use this test login I made:

> Email: test@hotmail.com
>
> Password: Testuser1

Also here is the `getCharacterData()` function that makes the AJAX call:

```
function getCharacterData(subject)
        {
        $.ajax({
                url: '/profile/getCharacterTripleData',
                type: 'GET',
                async: false,
                data: { field1: subject},
                success: function (data) {
                //your success code
                response = data;
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                //alert("Error: " + thrownError);
             }

            });

            return response;

        }
```

Comment: There is nothing as an update button in link you provided. Also, `<div>` tag don't have a `name` attribute. And where is your ajax call?

Comment: Can you show us the contents of the `getCharacterData` function?

Comment: @D4V1D Sorry forgot that you needed to be logged in to access that page.. see update

Comment: Can you show the HTML surrounding you `div`, since you speak of some form? Moreover, I think you cannot return the reponse like you did, but have instead to call a function in your success function (e.g., `receivedResult(data)`, and within this function you can do whatever you like with `data` (keep in mind, the whole point of an ajax call is that you get the result "later" and cannot return it directly).

Comment: @stef77 Here is the form before my div `<form class="ui form segment" name="form" id="myForm" method="POST" style="max-width:950px;">`

Comment: @stef77 As for the AJAX call, I can return it directly because I have set `async: false` as the call is only made on the click of the button so it is not asynchronous

Comment: Ah, sorry, have actually never seen `async: false` in reality, my bad. Couldn't you please edit your question and show the complete form you have? Your link responds with 404, so I can't figure it out from there. Do you have some code anywhere that's submitting the form?

Comment: @stef77 I have edited my question with the complete form and the function that submits the form. The link should also work now

Comment: I don't see a "character" section or an "update" button on the page you linked to?

Comment: That's because you have to login... see my EDIT

Comment: I did login, I can't see a button. Site seems to be down now. Do you have other elements with id `applyButton` in your HTML? Or some code that gets triggered on classes `submit` or `button`?

Comment: Ok, works again, you have to select "start new story" or something like that.

Comment: I see a different code than the one you posted: `<input class="ui blue submit button" id="applyButton" value = "Update" style="width:150px" name="apply"/>`. Please post exactly the code you're using, otherwise it's just a waste of time here.

Comment: @stef77 just click on the `Write` button in the main navigation bar to get to the page

Comment: @stef77 Please check again now

Comment: Have you tried changing your input type to button instead of form? You can just use the onlick event on an input button and then firm off the same events as a submit buitton. Sumbit button will always attempt to submit the form so it will refresh

Comment: @Canvas Instead of form? you mean instead of submit? Yes I have tried to change it to `input type="button"` and nothing changes. It's not a submit anyway it's a div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what JavaScript framework you're using. But your real source code contains `<input class="ui blue submit button" id="applyButton" value = "Update" style="width:150px" name="apply"/>`, not `<div class="ui blue submit button" id="applyButton" style="width:150px" name="apply">Update</div>`, as you claim. Perhaps there's some JavaScript adding a form submit to every input tag, I don't know, the JavaScripts are too big to debug.

Change it to `<div>`, as you described in your post, maybe that'll work.

Edit: Alternatively/additionally, some code might exist in your framework that gets triggered on classes submit or button. Remove those classes and try again.

Comment: Yes, you were right, the source was different to the one I posted but only slightly because I was testing on my local server. Have updated it now you can check it, same problem still occurs.

Comment: Throw away the css classes in the div. What happens now?

Comment: Ah that seems to have fixed it, I remove the `.submit` class and now it doesn't refresh. There must have been some back-end behaviour submitting the form when a button with `.submit` class was pressed. I am using Semantic UI framework so a lot of that stuff is under the bonnet. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help you. Please accept this answer with the green checkmark - question closed, reputation gains, benefits for everybody.

Comment: I would but your answer was not the solution, your comment was. People will get the assumption that changing it to a div fixed the problem but that wasn't the case. If you edit your answer and put something about removing the css classes I will accept it.

Comment: I edited my answer, but since you commented on your question "nothing that gets triggered on those classes", which was wrong, I doubt future users will benefit from this question. Feel free to accept or not.